# Are there any libraries for channel inversion?

Tags: language-agnostic, signal-processing, equalizer

I am trying to compensate for channel effects introduced into a waveform received over a mobile channel and the same waveform when received over a landline channel. Are there any libraries/code out there that do any one of the following:
1. Sound Equalization
2. Channel inversion/normalization

I have looked over the Internet and found nothing much. Any help is most welcome.

The libraries, if they exist, can be in any language, c/C++/Java/Python ... anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's impossible to compensate for a lossy or noise additive channel, which a mobile codec usually implements.

Comment: but are there any libraries that might attempt to do the same, however bad the attempt may be?